# Slim Framework adds <?php to json response

Tags: php, json, angularjs, slim

Working with Angular and Slim framework on an app. After a folder structure refactoring it appears that Slim is adding two `<?php` tags before the response body. Does anybody know what might be the reason? index.tmpl is plain html.

Sample code:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$view = $app->view();
$view->setTemplatesDirectory('./slimtmpl');
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
 $app->render('index.tmpl');
});

$app->get('/sample', 'sample');

function sample(){
 $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
 $response = $app->response();
 $response->write(json_encode($dummydata), 200);
}
```

And this is the response I get:

```
<?php<?php{"id":"1","dummy1":"asf","dummy2":"sdfsfsdf"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit(s): two empty php files were added and required in bootstrap.php